# ASP.NET How to assign .resx file to RadioButtonList

Tags: asp.net, resx

I have the radioButtonList on my page. I want to change that control's ListItems Text property depending on the .rex file. How to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind the text property: `Text="<%$ Resources:WebResources, RadioItemText %>"` in the ListItem element, if the items are embedded in the aspx. If they are generated programmatically, you have to store it in your viewmodel (using databind) or with add:

```
myRadioButtonList.Add(WebResources.ItemText1);
```

Comment: OK, but how to assign different values for each ListItem ?

Answer (score 0):

I stopped binding, and did things manually. Grabbed a dataset with two columns, ID and value.

```
    Dim rmHello As New ResourceManager("Resources.ResourceFileName", Assembly.Load(New AssemblyName("app_GlobalResources")))
    Dim dsData As DataSet
    Dim drData As DataRow
    Dim li As ListItem

    If Not IsNothing(dsData) AndAlso dsData.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            For Each drData In dsData.Tables(0).Rows
                li = New ListItem(rmHello.GetString(CStr(drData.Item("ID"))), CStr(drData.Item("value")))
                rbl.Items.Add(li)
            Next
        End If
```

I am sure the check for data, and posibly the reference to the table(0).Rows could be tidier, but I hope that is clearer for someone.